# From the perspective of the multiverse theory, would maths "work the same" in every possible Universe?

Tags: physics, philosophy

I've had an interesting discussion with a friend recently and I was arguing that in every possible Universe, mathematics would always have to work the same, i.e. $1 + 1 = 2$ would have to be true for every possible Universe, regardless of the laws of physics, number of physical dimensions etc. because in every Universe if you have one thing, and then another, you have two things in total. Another example: every possible Universe would have the same prime numbers and therefore the [Ulam spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral) would look the same in every possible Universe (with at least 2 dimensions).

Is this true? Is there an example that would prove this false?

Comment: The math should be the same, but not the same theories may be applicable to the same phenomena. Even in our home universe we may have that $1$ drop of water plus $1$ drop of water is still just $1$ (bigger) drop of water. This doesn't show that $1+1=1$ instead of $=2$, it shows that for *this* phenomenon, addition of natural numbers is not a suitable model.

Comment: Is mathematics not a part of the way in which we (humans) think? I mean, it is not like '$1+1 = 2$' has any meaning except in our heads (in fact, nothing really does...). But when we think of mathematics as something solely in our heads then it does not matter if we think about one universe or the other, the way we think about it won't change and so mathematics wouldn't either.

Comment: Yes, I agree that in alternative universes we might use alternative models to describe certain phenomena. This is the only part I can see changing. To give some more context, we were having a discussion involving cosmology and I was trying to show that there are things that would stay the same across all possible universes. I then hypothesised that e.g. if the Ulam spiral looks the same in every Universe and it's impossible for it to look different then perhaps the initial state of the Universe could not have been different. I know that's a bit farfetched and I digress...

Comment: IMHO, it is possible different universe has different math. The fundamental issue is the foundation we build modern math on, the logic system we have right now doesn't seem to describe the reality well once we get to sufficiently small length scale. In a universe when classical logic doesn't work, there are issues what the math should become. Maybe i should consult Living Tribunal for advice...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no reason to think that mathematics **would** be different in any other universe, nor that it **could** be different.

Answer (score 1):

Like every statement in natural language, every mathematical statement does not occur isolated but in a certain context. There are also undefinable concepts in any language, whether natural or not. "$1+1=2$" is only meaningful in a context where "$1$" and "$2$" and "$+$" and "$=$" are meaningful. If their meanings are completely determined, then that statement would be true no matter what. So it depends a lot on what exactly you define them to mean! What really is a "thing"?

To give a bit of detail, we could for example say that expressions that have the same value are equal, in which case we can write them down with an "$=$" in between. We could also define "$2$" to be a short-form for "$1+1$", and so both have the same value. Thus we get "$1+1=2$" as long as "$1$" and "$+$" are defined. Notice that I did not define what "value of an expression" means. That again is up to you to decide, but for most reasonable definitions what I said holds.

Also, there is little use for a multiverse theory because there must still be a single over-arching framework that governs what universes are allowed and how they interact. And hence we might as well consider that one single framework as the true universe.